# .NET Framework 4.7.2 can't call Assembly.GetTypes on a .NET 6.0 DLL

Tags: .net, .net-core, reflection

A .NET Framework 4.7.2 app calls `Assembly.LoadFrom` to load a .NET Core DLL:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\temp\mylib.dll");
```

Then it calls `myAssembly.GetTypes()` to get its types. It threw an exception:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. retrieve the loaderexceptions property for more information.

The DLL being loaded, `mylib.dll`, has a dependency on another DLL, which is in the same folder.

Why?

Comment: .NET Core and .NET Framework are incompatible, so such exceptions are expected and that's why.

Comment: However, the other way around works - .NET 6.0 code can do that to .NET Framework 4.7.2 DLL and it will work. I guess it is because .NET core are newer and therefore "backward compatible"?

Comment: Microsoft took all the trouble to enable some compatibility that .NET Core, however, can load some .NET Framework based libraries. But that’s really not something you should rely on either, as when it failed for you the difficulty to understand the failure isn’t smaller. Properly share code between the two via .NET Standard or conditional compilation, and you can avoid all such troubles.